# SQL returns all rows if "IN" subquery fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

So recently I caused myself a lot of trouble by coding to fast, not testing my code very well, and publishing a stored procedure with an error the compiler doesn't catch. I have a query like this:

```
--Lets say I have a table SomeTable (SomeId, CreateDate, UpdatedDate)

DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Id INT);

INSERT INTO @Temp (Id)
SELECT SomeId FROM SomeTable WHERE CreateDate > SomeDate;

UPDATE SomeTable 
SET UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE SomeId IN (SELECT TempId FROM @Temp);
```

Now the compiler didn't catch that I was trying to select a column in my sub query that didn't exist in my temp table (which I get). However, in my mind if the sub query fails in this case wouldn't it make sense that no rows should be returned. When I ran this EVERY ROW EVER  in SomeTable was updated. Which, as you can imagine, was a huge pain to fix. Does any one have a clue why it does this? I can't seem to find the answer online.

Comment: Does `SomeTable` contain a column name `TempId`? If yes, then this is how the SQL standard defines the visibility of columns in a sub-select.

Comment: why not UPDATE SomeTable 
SET UpdatedDate = GETDATE() where CreateDate > SomeDate;

Comment: This was just an on the fly example. This isn't really what the code was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You think you wrote this query:

```
UPDATE SomeTable  s
SET UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE s.SomeId IN (SELECT t.TempId FROM @Temp t);
```

But, if `t.TempId` doesn't exist, then SQL Server (and all other databases) interpret this as:

```
UPDATE SomeTable  s
SET UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE s.SomeId IN (SELECT s.TempId FROM @Temp t);
```

If you are getting all rows, then there is a column `SomeTable.TempId` that has the same value as `SomeTable.SomeId`.  My guess is that you used the same column name in the two places.  So, your query is essentially `SomeTable.SomeId = SomeId` -- which is true whenever `SomeId` is not `NULL`.

If you follow the bets practice of always qualifying your columns names with a table alias, then you would not have had this problem.  If you had done that, then the first version of the query would have failed, probably with an intelligible error.

Comment: If `tempId` was qualified with an alias in the sub-select then it _should_ throw an error. The ambiguity with the column name in the sub-select only occurs when the column name is not qualified with an alias (or table name)

Comment: The alias thing would have kept me out of trouble. Not sure why I didn't think of that.